# Report sorting month numbers incorrectly

Tags: c#, sql, rdlc

This is pretty odd, since I made matrixes before with years/months but now for some reason the months are going: 1, 10, 11, 12, 3, 4, 5 etc...

The problem:

[image: The problem]

The sorting is fine in SQL Server, and the data the graph is showing is correct. It worked before when I tried it with other columns, but now it's messing up. It's using a DataSet as source that has following:

Godina(Year) as Int32,
Mjesec(Month) as Int32 and
BrojNarudzbi(Number of orders) as Int32, listed in DataTable in that order. This procedure is where I'm getting the records from, if it helps:

```
begin
Select Count(NarudzbeID) as 'BrojNarudzbi', Month(N.DatumNarudzbe) as 'Mjesec', Year(N.DatumNarudzbe) as 'Godina'
from Narudzbe as N
Group by  Year(N.DatumNarudzbe), Month(N.DatumNarudzbe)
Order by Year(N.DatumNarudzbe), Month(N.DatumNarudzbe)
```

Again, the data that's being displayed is correct, just months are not being sorted for some odd reason.

Comment: I think you might be sorting the numbers as strings rather than numbers.  1, 12, 3 would work that way.

Comment: It is alphabetical order as if there were strings. Try to add '0' before one digit month

Comment: Why is this posting has c# as Tag.  There is no c# code.  All you are showing is the SQL query results.  So what isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify data type in the dataset for this column.

It is alphabetical order as if there were strings. Try to add `'0'` before one digit months.

```
begin
Select Count(NarudzbeID) as 'BrojNarudzbi', 
  right('0'+cast(Month(N.DatumNarudzbe) as varchar(2)),2) as 'Mjesec', 
  Year(N.DatumNarudzbe) as 'Godina'
from Narudzbe as N
Group by  Year(N.DatumNarudzbe), Month(N.DatumNarudzbe)
Order by Year(N.DatumNarudzbe), Month(N.DatumNarudzbe)
```

Comment: How would I go about 10th, 11th and 12th month then? I removed what you did with the years since it changes them all to 0*, but now months only go 1-9

Comment: but it is more relevant to verify data type for the column in the dataset

Comment: They are all System.Int32, and Month and Year functions are supposed to return ints anyway, I have no idea why they would behave like strings

Comment: This is a simple matrix in a Report maker in Visual Studio, .rdlc extension. I checked the data set in report datasources, all int32s, I might have missed something because I did get this to work properly before, but this solution will do for now